# Optional mixin argument, set default value as value of another argument in LESS?

Tags: less

Can the optional `@font-file` argument get the value of `@font-name` in LESS? Without any javascript evaluation...

```
.font-face(@font-name, @font-file: ???) {
    font-family: '@{font-name}';
    src: url('fonts/@{font-file}.eot');
    src: url('fonts/@{font-file}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/@{font-file}.svg#@{font-file}') format('svg'),
         url('fonts/@{font-file}.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/@{font-file}.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Sorry if it's quite noobish-question, I've spent about 2 hours with LESS by now :)

**EDIT**: without duplicating the mixin:

```
.font-face(@font-file) {
    .font-face(@font-file, @font-file)
}

.font-face(@font-name, @font-file) {
  font-family: '@{font-name}';
  src: url('fonts/@{font-file}.eot');
  src: url('fonts/@{font-file}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('fonts/@{font-file}.svg#@{font-file}') format('svg'),
  url('fonts/@{font-file}.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/@{font-file}.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my knowledge is "No." LESS uses only pattern matching and guard expressions to do such evaluations, so there is no way to do another type of "if" condition that might be used to set the `font-file` name.

Your "duplicating" mixin is not really a "duplicate" according to LESS, as one matches the pattern of having only *one* variable passed, whereas the other matches the pattern of having *two* variables passed. So your solution is the correct (and probably most elegant) way to achieve what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually supply a default value in the declaration:

```
.border-radius(@radius: 5px) {
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
     -moz-border-radius: @radius;
          border-radius: @radius;
}
```

And then use it with or without the extra argument:

```
#header {
  .border-radius;
}
```

See: http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature